# Is Kubernetes reporting the incorrect memory capacity?

Tags: kubernetes

When I ssh in to my box and run the following, I can see I have 26.8 GB of ram.

```
cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemTotal | awk '{ print $2 }'
26814064
```

So why does Kube-UI report 27.46 GB (which is higher than I expected)..

[image: kube-ui]

and `kubectl describe nodes` report 3.43 GB (which is much lower that I expected)?

```
kubectl describe nodes gke-cluster-2-75125dbd-node-q9v6 | grep memory
 memory:        26814064Ki
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numbers are correct, you are probably confused with the units:

26814064 **KiB** (Kibibyte) = 27,4576 **GB** (Gigabyte)